# The number of consecutive odd integers whose sum can be expressed as $50^2-13^2$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Here i have a question that

To find the number of consecutive odd integers whose sum can be expressed as $50^2-13^2$

Just i am unable to understand the question what is really it is asking. Please someone explain me.

Comment: I.e., how many (2n+1)+(2n+3).. etc is equal to (63*37)

Comment: I am somewhat getting it....i m trying..

Comment: But i think there should be the reason of giving $50^2-13^2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have
$$1+ 3 +...+(2n-1) = n^2 $$
hence 
$$50^2 -13^2 =1+3 +...+99 -(1+3+...+25) =27 +29 +...+99$$

Comment: Pratyush, has just to count the numbers.

Comment: Then answer should be 37 . Am i right?

Comment: Yes you're right.

Comment: But this is not the only solution, because $50^2-13^2$ can be expressed in other ways as a difference of two squares. For instance, $50^2-13^2 = 63 \times 37 = 21 \times 111 = 66^2-45^2$.